# Replace cURL with HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have seen [How do I replace curl invoke with HttpClient object invoke or some similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532155/how-do-i-replace-curl-invoke-with-httpclient-object-invoke-or-some-similar) but it didn't answer my question. I have been given the below cURL command by our vendor, with some optional parameters, and instructions to use a CRON job to run it. It seems it would be more efficient to send the CSV my C# code is generating via HttpClient rather than dropping the CSV somewhere and going through the CRON job business. The C# I am writing will be part of an automation service we already have in place.

Here is the cURL:

```
curl -F "passkey=<PASS KEY>" -F "uploadFile=@<PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE>" https://td-setup.xxxxxx.com/<DOMAIN NAME>/csvupload
```

There is a loadAll parameter that I will want to use.

I have added Microsoft.Net.Http -Version 2.2.22 to my project via NuGet, and now find myself not sure what to do next. Sadly, this is all the further I've gotten:

```
       string baseAddress = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", taskConfig.Upload.BaseUrl, domain.Username, taskConfig.Upload.UploadLocation);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient)
        {

        }
```

I typically like to have demonstrated more of an effort before asking her help, but I'm over my head. How do I begin? Add the passkey? the loadAll parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `curl -F` option indicates POST data using the `multipart/form-data` content type as per [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt).

So you need to create a [`MultipartFormDataContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.118).aspx) object:

```
var formDataContent= new MultipartFormDataContent();
```

Attach your password string to it:

```
// passkey is the param name from the curl script
formDataContent.Add(new HttpStringContent("yourpasswordhere"), "passkey");
```

Attach your CSV file content to it:

```
byte[] csvBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("yourcsvfile.csv");
var csvContent = new ByteArrayContent(csvBytes);

// uploadFile is the param name specified in the curl script
formDataContent.Add(csvContent, "uploadFile", "filename.csv");
```

You don't explain how the loadAll parameter is used in curl but lets pretend it's a 'true'/'false' string parameter:

```
formDataContent.Add(new HttpStringContent("true"), "loadAll");
```

Finally post the form:

```
string url = "https://td-setup.xxxxxx.com/<DOMAIN NAME>/csvupload";
var client = new HttpClient();
await client.PostAsync(url, formDataContent);
```